# How do I use the DATEDIF function to calculate the difference between two dates in years?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

How do I use the DATEDIF function to calculate the difference between two dates in years, months, and days? What is the correct syntax for using DATEDIF, and are there any specific formatting requirements for the input dates?

DATEDIF

```
=DATEDIF(B7; C7; "D")
=DATEDIF(C7; TODAY(); "D")
```

I want no result in cell `D7`, `E7` to appear when there are no results in cell `B7`, `C7`.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HBMNjnv-Kfqp7nMe-oFR9a24w2nly21UukmVGurAwgs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304) to replace the `#NUM!` with an empty string:

```
=IFERROR(DATEDIF(B7; C7; "D"); "")
```

`IFERROR` will normally return the result of the first argument (in the case `DATEDIF`).
But in case the first expression results in an error, it will return the second argument instead.

Edit:
For the second example you need to check if the value in `C7` is valid date, because `DATEDIF(""; TODAY(); "D")` will return the days since `01.01.1990`.
You can do this by using [`ISDATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9061381) & [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364):

```
=IF(ISDATE(C7); DATEDIF(C7; TODAY(); "D"); "")
```

You could also use this method for the first datedif:

```
=IF(AND(ISDATE(B7); ISDATE(C7)); DATEDIF(B7; C7; "D"); "")
```

Comment: The function: = IFERROR (DATEDIF (B7; C7; "D"); "") worked, but the function = IFERROR (DATEDIF (C7; TODAY (); "D"); "") didn't work, always shows the fixed amount 43682

Comment: @Glaucco you're right, i updated my answer with a solution that also covers the second case.

Comment: @Glaucco Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Glaucco Turtlefight gave you an answer that solved your problem. It would be polite to accept it as your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the site, I chose the best answer.